# Handle data insertion after validation

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have an application that has a form. Validation and data insertion works fine. However, it bulks out my controller. I've always been told **skinny** controllers.

For example:

```
class myController extends BaseController
{
    public function store(myRequest $request)
    {
        $company_id = Company::insertGetId([
            'name'      => $request->name, 
            'contact'   => $request->contact, 
            'email'     => $request->email, 
            'telephone' => $request->telephone, 
        ]);

       $this->handleQuestion($request->question_one, '1', $company_id->id);
       $this->handleQuestion($request->question_two, '2', $company_id->id);
       $this->handleQuestion($request->question_three, '3', $company_id->id);
       $this->handleQuestion($request->question_four, '4', $company_id->id);
       $this->handleQuestion($request->question_five, '5', $company_id->id);
       $this->handleQuestion($request->question_six, '6', $company_id->id);
       $this->handleQuestion($request->question_seven, '7', $company_id->id);

       Outstanding::create([
            'company_id' => $company_id->id, 
       ]);
    }

    public function handleQuestion($answer, $q_id, $company_id)
    {
        if( $question ) {
            CompanyAnswers::create([
                'company_id'  => $company_id, 
                'question_id' => $q_id, 
                'answer'      => $answer, 
            ]);      
        }   
    }
}
```

The database schema has been created with a 2NF relation in mind.

**`companies`**

- `id` (PK)
- `name`
- `contact`
- `email`
- `telephone`

**`company_answers`**

- `id` (PK)
- `company_id` (FK)
- `question_id` (FK)
- `answer`

**`outstanding_companies`**

- `id` (PK)
- `company_id` (FK)
- `question_id` (FK)
- `answer`

### How is the application intended to work?

- When the form is filled out, we create the `company`.
- We ask seven questions - questions are **not** mandatory. (This is why we have a `company_answers` table - to avoid redundant data.) The results of the questions are stored in `company_answers`.
- We insert the application in `outstanding_companies` so we know that this application is outstanding and needs attention.

### My Problem

1. Have I totally misunderstood database normalisation and hindered myself by adding more code to handle data insertion?
2. If I have understood database normalisation, what is a better approach for handling the data insertion?
3. Is **skinny** controllers true? If so, where do I put data insertion logic?

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of digging, I have finally arrived at (what I think) a better solution.

Laravel had a feature in 5.0 called `CommandBus` with 5.1 they have changed the name & the class structure (slightly) to `Jobs`.

`Jobs` are Queuable or you can run them synchronously. The real benefit from using jobs are:

- Loosely coupled to the controller
- Easier testing
- Re-usable

This was a really good feature for me & my project because an application can be submitted in multiple controllers.

After implementation my controller now looks like this:

```
public function postGuest(Requests\VoucherFormRequest $request)
{
    //return the newly created id
    $company_id     = $this->dispatchFrom('App\Jobs\CreateCompanyJob', $request);

    //set the application to outstanding
    $outstanding_id = $this->dispatch(new SetApplicationToOutstandingJob($company_id));

    //return the user_id this application needs mapping to.
    $userId         = $this->dispatch(new InsertApplicationAnswersJob($request->only('question'), $company_id));

    //finally map the application to the user chosen by our auto delegation.
    $this->dispatch(new MapOutstandingAppToUserJob($outstanding_id, $userId));

    return redirect(route('guest-published'));
}
```

This is the solution that I have found & seems to be a huge improvement on what I had. Most likely, there will be a better solution so feedbacks always welcome!

### Handling Questions

Handling questions was done by putting them in a multidimensional array within my form.

```
{!! Form::text('question[6]', '', array('class' => 'app-create-input')) !!}
```

With this approach all I had to do was iterate through the array & handle each parameter within the loop.

```
foreach ($this->answers as $key => $value) {
    CompanyAnswers::create([
        'company_id'  => $this->company_id,
        'question_id' => $key,
        'answer'      => $value
    ]);
}
```

### Normalisation

In regards to my normalisation, I cannot see any glaring issues. Even after further research. However I don't claim to be a `DBA` so I could very well be missing something.